# Erro na resolução de um sistema linear

Tags: python, matriz, script, syntax-error

Prezada (o),

Estou resolvendo um problema de diferença finita, o código está correto, porém ao resolver o sistema linear, apresenta mensagem de erro.

Poderia me ajudar por favor?

````
import numpy as np 
def p(x):
  return 0
def q(x):
  return 0
def r(x):
  return -100

def diffinita(x0,y0,xf,yf,N):
  # Variáveis iniciais
  delta_x = (xf-x0)/N
  vetor_x = np.linspace(x0+delta_x,xf-delta_x,N-1)
  dim_sist = N-1 
  A = np.zeros((dim_sist,dim_sist))
  print(A)
  b = np.zeros(dim_sist)
  print(b)

  # Elaboração da matriz 
  for i in range(dim_sist):
    x = vetor_x[i]
    for j in range(dim_sist):
      if i==j:
        A[i][j]=2+q(x)*pow(delta_x,2)
      elif i==(j+1):
        A[i][j]=-1-(p(x)*delta_x)/2
      elif i==(j-1):
        A[i][j]=-1+(p(x)*delta_x)/2
      else:
        A[i][j]=0
    # Montagem vetor b 
    for i in range(dim_sist):
      x = vetor_x[i]
      if i==0:
        b[i]= (1+p(x)*delta_x/2)*y0-r(x)*pow(delta_x,2)
      elif i==(dim_sist-1):
        b[i]= (1-p(x)*delta_x/2)*yf-r(x)*pow(delta_x,2)
      else:
        b[i]=-r(x)*pow(delta_x,2)

    y = np.linalg.solve(A,b) # Esta declaração que apresenta o erro 
    
  return y

  



y = diffinita(0,0,0.1,0,4)

for i in range(len(y)):
  print("y=",y[i])

```
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-0a078b885b7b> in <module>()
     47 
     48 
---> 49 y = diffinita(0,0,0.1,0,4)
     50 
     51 for i in range(len(y)):

2 frames
<__array_function__ internals> in solve(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag)
     86 
     87 def _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag):
---> 88     raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
     89 
     90 def _raise_linalgerror_nonposdef(err, flag):

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
````

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está de acordo com o a matriz que seu código produz. Segundo a [documentação](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) da função `numpy.linalg.solve`, esse erro é erguido quando a matriz é [singular](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_singular). Matrizes singulares possuem determinante nulo, e o sistema por elas representado não possui solução única  (apresentando zero ou infinitas soluções).

Podemos confirmar a singularidade de `A` se modificarmos o seu código para:

```
# ...

print(A)
y = np.linalg.solve(A,b) # Esta declaração que apresenta o erro

# ...
```

Vemos que, imediatamente antes da linha que ergue o erro, a matriz `A` tem esses valores:

```
[[ 2. -1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

É facilmente perceptível por análise visual (mas também checável com `np.linalg.det(A)`) que a matriz tem determinante zero, e portanto é singular.